# Open an URL in Safari with Private Browsing

Tags: macos, safari, command-line

I want to open an URL in a browser's private mode.
`--args -incognito` does the job with Chromium-based browsers (e.g. `open -na "Google Chrome" --args -incognito http://www.example.com`).
I tried `-incognito`, `-private`, `-private-browsing` arguments, but none worked with Safari.
What's a Safari's command option to open in private mode?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Safari** does not have similar *command line options* like **Google Chrome**, however, here is a way to *roll your own*:

In **Terminal**, run the following *compound command*:

```
touch safari; open -e safari; chmod +x safari
```

Copy and paste the *example* **AppleScript** *code*, shown further below, into the opened **safari** *document*, then save it.

You should then move the `safari` *shell script* to a *directory* located within the *shell's* `PATH`.

I moved it to `/usr/local/bin`, e.g,:

```
sudo mv -v safari /usr/local/bin/
```

Now from **Terminal** I can open a new private *window* for **Safari**. 
 Typing just the executable's *name* without any *arguments* shows how it can be used e.g,:

```
% safari
Missing Arguments!...
Examples:
safari https://www.example.com
safari -private
safari -private https://www.example.com
%
```

---

**Notes**:

- As coded, the *example* **AppleScript** *code* is focused on opening a new private *window*, however, as you can see it can open a normal new *window* to the provided **URL** too. For the new private *window*, you can open it with or without passing it a **URL**.
- As coded, the *example* **AppleScript** *code* only allow for one **URL** to be passed at a time. Additional *coding* is required to allow passing multiple **URLs**.

---

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
#!/usr/bin/osascript

on run args
    
    if args is {} then return ¬
        "Missing Arguments!..." & linefeed & ¬
        "Examples:" & linefeed & ¬
        "safari https://www.example.com" & linefeed & ¬
        "safari -private" & linefeed & ¬
        "safari -private https://www.example.com"       
    
    set newPrivateWindow to false
    
    if item 1 of args contains "-private" then
        set newPrivateWindow to true
        if (length of args) is not greater than 1 then
            set theURL to missing value
        else
            set theURL to item 2 of args
        end
    else
        set theURL to item 1 of args
    end if
    
    tell application "Safari" to activate
    delay 1
    
    if newPrivateWindow then
        tell application "System Events" to ¬
            keystroke "n" using ¬
                {shift down, command down}
        delay 1
        openURL(theURL)
    else
        tell application "System Events" to ¬
            keystroke "n" using ¬
                {command down}
        delay 1
        openURL(theURL)
    end if
    
end run

on openURL(theURL)
    if theURL is missing value then
        return
    else
        tell application "Safari" to ¬
            set URL of ¬
                current tab of ¬
                front window to ¬
                theURL as string
    end if
end openURL
```