# Terminal command to force open new tab in Safari

Tags: terminal, safari, web-browser, tabs

While running the `open https://www.google.com` command in Terminal consecutive times, I have noticed the second time I run the command it just shows the original window of google.com instead of opening in a new tab. It works fine when its a different website being requested.

Is this a macOS bug? I've tried setting new tabs to always in Safari but no luck.

I'm trying to get Safari to always open a new tab even if its the same website. FYI I have a for stock alerts and automatically opens default browser new tab ​upon stock being found using Terminal however it doesn't open new tabs correctly as described above.

Answer (score 1):

This Terminal command should accomplish what you are looking for.

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Safari" to activate' -e 'tell application "Safari" to tell window 1 to set URL of (make new tab) to "https://www.google.com"' -e 'tell application "Safari" to tell window 1 to set current tab to last tab'
```

Answer (score 1):

As the `open` *command* does not produce the desired results, here is an adaptation of my answer [A: Open an URL in Safari with Private Browsing](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/416297/open-an-url-in-safari-with-private-browsing/416349?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C20.7510#416349) that will easily allow you to open a **URL** from the *command line* in a new *tab* of a **Safari** *window*, whether or not a *tab* with that **URL** already exists..

It works whether or not **Safari** is running, and if running, whether or not a *window* already exists.

In **Terminal**, run the following *compound command*:

```
f='openurl'; touch "$f"; open -e "$f"; chmod +x "$f"
```

Copy and paste the *example* **AppleScript** *code*, shown below, into the opened **openurl** *document*, then save it.

You should then move the `openurl` *shell script* to a *directory* located within the *shell's* `PATH`.

I moved it to `/usr/local/bin`, e.g,:

```
sudo mv -v openurl /usr/local/bin/
```

Now from **Terminal** I can open the same **URL** in a new *tab* **Safari** whether or not a *tab* with that **URL** already exists.

Typing just the executable's *name* without any *arguments* shows how it can be used e.g,:

```
% openurl
Missing URL...
Example: openurl 'https://www.example.com'
%
```

---

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
#!/usr/bin/osascript

on run args
    if args is {} then return ¬
        "Missing URL..." & linefeed & ¬
        "Example: " & (name of me) & space & "'https://www.example.com'"
    
    set theURL to first item of args as string
    
    if not running of application id "com.apple.Safari" then
        tell application id "com.apple.Safari"
            activate
            set i to 0
            repeat until exists window 1
                delay 0.1
                set i to i + 1
                if i ≥ 40 then return
            end repeat
            set URL of current tab of window 1 to theURL
        end tell
    else
        tell application id "com.apple.Safari"
            if exists window 1 then
                tell window 1 to set URL of (make new tab) to theURL
            else
                make new document with properties {URL: theURL}
            end if
        end tell
    end if
end run
```

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and sans any included *error handling* does not contain any additional *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>